# regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to merge these two regular expressions?

- `/^[A-Za-z]\S{3,30}$/`
- `/^(?:(\w)(?!\1\1))+$/`

I would like a string of:

- only letters,
- length between 3 and 30,
- no spaces,
- no to the repetition of the same letter more than two consecutive times (e.g: 'ddd' //false, 'dtdddyyt' //false, 'dtddyyt'//true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1{2})){3,30}$/
/^(?:(\p{Alphabetic})(?!\1{2})){3,30}$/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNNZvH/1). **Note**:

- *only letters* - `[A-Za-z]` / `\p{L}` or `\p{Alphabetic}` (available in ECMAScript 2018+ compliant JS environments with `/u` flag)
- *length between 3 and 30* - `{3,30}`
- *no spaces* - this condition is already covered by the first one
- *no to the repetition of the same letter more than two consecutive times* - `([A-Za-z])(?!\1{2})`.

JavaScript test:

```js
const rx = /^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1{2})){3,30}$/;
const texts = ["ddad","dtddyyt","adaddd","dtdddyyt","ddd"];
for (let text of texts) {
  console.log(text, "=>", rx.test(text));
}
```

*More details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (used as a container of a pattern sequence):

  - `([A-Za-z])` - Group 1: an ASCII letter (`\p{L}` / `\p{Alphabetic}` matches any Unicode letter)
  - `(?!\1{2})` - right after the letter, there should not be two occurrences of the same letter
- `)` - end of the group
- `{3,30}` - match three to thirty consecutive occurrences of the pattern sequence inside the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second pattern as a negative lookahead assertion once to not match `ddd` in the string.

```
^(?!\S*(\w)\1\1)[A-Za-z]\S{3,30}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `\S*(\w)\1\1` Match optional non whitespace chars, capture a word char and match the same with 2 backreferences
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[A-Za-z]\S{3,30}` Match a single char A-Za-z and 3-30 non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UgCT5w/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!\S*(\w)\1\1)[A-Za-z]\S{3,30}$/;
[
  "ddad",
  "dtddyyt",
  "adaddd",
  "dtdddyyt",
  "ddd"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```